Failing to load plugin in Gazebo Fortress
Ros Humble/Ignition Fortress/Ubuntu 22.04
Hey Ya'll, I'm attempting to load a UR10e into Gazebo Fortress so I can control it with Moveit, and I'm running into an issue. To start, I modified the generated ros2_control.xacro file so that it included the needed plugins for the controller manager:
    <xacro:macro name="robot_gazebo_control" params="name initial_positions_file">
        <xacro:property name="initial_positions" value="${load_yaml(initial_positions_file)['initial_positions']}"/>

        <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>ign_ros2_control/IgnitionSystem</plugin>
            </hardware>
            
            <!-- Manipulator Joints -->
            <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-3.14</param>
                <param name="max">3.14</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['shoulder_pan_joint']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-1.57</param>
            <param name="max">1.57</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position">
            <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['shoulder_lift_joint']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="elbow_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-3.14</param>
                <param name="max">3.14</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['elbow_joint']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="wrist_1_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-3.14</param>
            <param name="max">3.14</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position">
            <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['wrist_1_joint']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="wrist_2_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">-3.14</param>
                <param name="max">3.14</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['wrist_2_joint']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="wrist_3_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-3.14</param>
            <param name="max">3.14</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position">
            <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['wrist_3_joint']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
            </joint>
            
            <!-- Gripper Joint -->
            <joint name="robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <param name="min">0.0</param>
                <param name="max">0.8</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint']}</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
    <gazebo>
      <!-- Ignition Gazebo ROS2 control plugin -->
    <plugin filename="ign_ros2_control-system" name="ign_ros2_control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin">
          <parameters>$(find robot_moveit_config)/config/ros2_controllers.yaml</parameters>
          </plugin>
        </gazebo>
    </xacro:macro>

I copied the gazebo and hardware plugins from the ign_ros2_control_demo example here
I then copied and modified the launch file from the same example:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


import os
import xacro

def generate_launch_description():
    # Launch Arguments
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default=True)

    spud_master_moveit_config_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('robot_moveit_config'))

    xacro_file = os.path.join(robot_moveit_config_path,
                              'config',
                              'robot.urdf.xacro')

    doc = xacro.parse(open(xacro_file))
    xacro.process_doc(doc)
    params = {'robot_description': doc.toxml()}

    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )

    ignition_spawn_entity = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-string', doc.toxml(),
                   '-name', 'robot',
                   '-allow_renaming', 'true'],
    )

    load_joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'joint_state_broadcaster'],
        output='screen'
    )

    load_joint_trajectory_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'manipulator_controller'],
        output='screen'
    )

    load_gripper_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'gripper_controller'],
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        # Launch gazebo environment
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                [os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ros_ign_gazebo'),
                              'launch', 'ign_gazebo.launch.py')]),
            launch_arguments=[('gz_args', [' -r -v 4 empty.sdf'])]),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=ignition_spawn_entity,
                on_exit=[load_joint_state_broadcaster],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=load_joint_state_broadcaster,
                on_exit=[load_joint_trajectory_controller],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=load_joint_trajectory_controller,
                on_exit=[load_gripper_controller],
            )
        ),
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        ignition_spawn_entity,
        # Launch Arguments
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value=use_sim_time,
            description='If true, use simulated clock'),
    ])


When launching, this error appears:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1718206910.755951737] [gz_ros2_control]: The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class mock_components/GenericSystem with base class type ign_ros2_control::IgnitionSystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  ign_ros2_control/IgnitionSystem

which subsequently leads to this error:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1718206913.472056748] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'gripper_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1718206913.478586584] [gripper_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1718206913.483060042] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'gripper_controller'
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [WARN] [1718206913.483231156] [gripper_controller]: 'joints' parameter is empty.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [INFO] [1718206913.483281593] [gripper_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1718206913.483310744] [gripper_controller]: 'command_interfaces' parameter is empty.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1718206913.483356589] [controller_manager]: After configuring, controller 'gripper_controller' is in state 'unconfigured' , expected inactive.
[ros2-6] Error configuring controller

and no loaded controllers. Is this the correct way to load controllers, or am I missing a configuration step that's causing this behavior? Finally, are there any tutorials that walk through the process of setting up controllers for ignition gazebo step-by-step that I can use to guide me in the future?

Are you sure that you don't have another plugin tag in your xacro file?
Search for something like mock_components/GenericSystem. You can also use xacro <path-to-your-file> > robot.urdf to generate the full URDF for analysis.
The subsequent errors are not related, you just have misconfigured your controller. Set the command_interfaces as the error message suggests. You haven't posted your ros2_controllers.yaml, but it seems to be a joint_trajectory_controller.
